# Mouse Event in Outline View

Tags: cocoa, mouseevent, nsoutlineview

I have a window which contains a split view. One of the "splits" contains an outline view. I have a window controller (which is the file owner for the window's XIB). The window controller is the delegate and data source of the outline view.

When I call the `-(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)e` method in the window controller only the toolbar responds to the method - the outline view does not.

How do I get the mouse events, e.g. the mouseDown, of the outline view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the mouse event of the outline view:

1. Subclass the outline view.

   - In Interface Builder (IB) > Library panel > Classes tab  select NSOutlineView
   - Right-click NSOutlineView and select "New Subclass..."
   - Complete the following pop-up windows selecting "Generate Source Files" and add the fils to your project
   - Select the NSOutlineView
   - In Inspector Panel > Identity tab > Class Identity > Class  select your new class
2. Implement your mouse event method

   - In Xcode > your new subclass of your outline view > the implementation (.m) file type your method e.g.

     ```
     (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
         /* CODE YOU WANT EXECUTED WHEN MOUSE IS CLICKED */
         NSLog(@"Mouse down occurred");
         // call this to get the usual behaviour of your outline
         // view in addition to your custom code
         [super mouseDown:theEvent];
     }
     ```

It may be useful to know that one can get mouse events by using `[NSEvent modifierFlags]`. This is will work not just for the outline view but for views throughout the app. For example, in the window controller (referred to in the question) I could include code like:

```
if ([NSEvent modifierFlags] == NSAlternateKeyMask) { // if the option key is being pressed
            /*SOME CODE*/
}
```